# Possible Warehouse 13 continuity discrepancy in the recent Living and the Dead Episode?

Tags: continuity, warehouse-13

I just watched the 2nd half of the Warehouse13 Episode "The Living and the Dead", and wanted to see if I missed something in the flow with which the folks here can help.

Spoiler Alert

> When Myka and Pete restore the Orchid using the ring, we see a scene in which the Sweating sickness leaves all the infected people/nations.  As part of that, in one shot, we see the sickness leaving--i.e. coming out of the mouths of--Mrs. Frederick, Jinks AND Claudia who is standing next to the others facing the camera with her eyes open.  In that scene she doesn't seem to be holding Artie's hand.  However, in a subsequent shot we see Claudia still sitting down holding Artie's hand with her eyes closed.

Is this a continuity discrepancy, or am I missing something in the episode that explains this?

Thank you.

[Warehouse 13 episode listings](http://www.syfy.com/warehouse13/episodes)

Comment: Sounds like a scene and production gaffe more than anything else. When a scene is being filmed, they may cut to shoot from a different angle or with a different camera and not reset the scene quite the same way as before. This happens all the time in filming. I wouldn't pay any attention to it at all.